# rolling_mean instability in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm performing an upgrade from our current environment (Python 2.7.3 64-bit, pandas 0.9) to a new one (Python 2.7.6, pandas 0.14.1) and some of my regression tests are failing.  I tracked it down to the behavior of `pandas.stats.moments.rolling_mean`

Here is a sample to reproduce the error:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    1.0,
    0.99997000000000003,
    0.99992625131299995,
    0.99992500140499996,
    0.99986125618599997,
    0.99981126312299995,
    0.99976377208800005,
    0.99984375318999996]
ser = pd.Series(data, index=pd.date_range('2008-05-28', '2008-06-06', freq='B'))

print "rolling mean: %.17f" % pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(ser, window=5, min_periods=1)['2008-06-06']
print "sum divide:   %.17f" % (ser['2008-6-1':'2008-6-6'].sum()/5)
```

In my original environment, I get the following output:

```
rolling mean: 0.99984100919839991                                                   
sum divide:   0.99984100919839991
```

but in my new environment the output is now:

```
rolling mean: 0.99984100919840002                                                   
sum divide:   0.99984100919839991
```

As you can see, the rolling mean now gives a slightly different number.  It's a small difference for sure, but the errors get compounded and it ends up being non-trivial.

Does anyone know what could be causing it or if there's a workaround?

Comment: This would be better as an issue on github. Mind creating one?

Comment: @TomAugspurger Given Yoel's answer, I don't think this is necessarily an issue, although it would be nice if it was documented in the release notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the difference in the outcome of the different approaches is an accumulated rounding error that is greater during the *sum divide* computation. In the past, the *rolling mean* computation suffered from a similar issue, but it seems that internal improvements in its algorithm over the past few versions have brought it to a more precise result.

First of all, let's establish that the new *rolling mean* result is more precise. We shall do it by invoking the *sum divide* approach twice, but each time with a different precision:

```
In [166]: ser1 = pd.Series(data, index=pd.date_range('2008-05-28', '2008-06-06', freq='B'))

In [167]: type(ser1[0])
Out[167]: numpy.float64

In [168]: print "sum divide:   %.17f" % (ser1['2008-6-1':'2008-6-6'].sum()/5)
sum divide:   0.99984100919839991

In [169]: ser2 = pd.Series(data, index=pd.date_range('2008-05-28', '2008-06-06', freq='B'), dtype = np.float128)

In [170]: print "sum divide:   %.17f" % (ser2['2008-6-1':'2008-6-6'].sum()/5)
sum divide:   0.99984100919840002
```

Using the greater `np.float128` precision results in a value closer to that of the new *rolling mean* version. This clearly proves that the new *rolling mean* version is more precise than the previous one.

This also suggests a possible workaround to your problem - employ a greater precision in your calculations by defining your series to hold objects of `np.float128`. This improves the precision of the *sum divide* approach, but doesn't affect that of the *rolling mean* approach:

```
In [185]: pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(ser1, window=5, min_periods=1) == pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(ser2, window=5, min_periods=1)
Out[185]: 
2008-05-28    True
2008-05-29    True
2008-05-30    True
2008-06-02    True
2008-06-03    True
2008-06-04    True
2008-06-05    True
2008-06-06    True
Freq: B, dtype: bool
```

Note that even though this brings the results of each of the approaches closer together, and they even seem identical:

```
In [194]: print "sum divide:   %.60f" % (ser2['2008-6-1':'2008-6-6'].sum()/5)
sum divide:   0.999841009198400021418251526483800262212753295898437500000000

In [195]: print "rolling mean: %.60f" % pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(ser2, window=5, min_periods=1)['2008-06-06']
rolling mean: 0.999841009198400021418251526483800262212753295898437500000000
```

from the processor's point of view, they still differ:

```
In [196]: pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(ser2, window=5, min_periods=1)['2008-06-06'] == ser2['2008-6-1':'2008-6-6'].sum()/5
Out[196]: False

In [197]: pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(ser2, window=5, min_periods=1)['2008-06-06'] - ser2['2008-6-1':'2008-6-6'].sum()/5
Out[197]: 4.4398078963281406573e-17
```

but hopefully the margin of error, which is a bit smaller now, falls in within your use-case.

Comment: I think you are right about the change in the `rolling_mean` algorithm, although I was unable to find it documented in release docs for any of the versions.  I was able to get the more precise value in my previous environment by doing the incremental update to cumulative mean instead of taking a batch sum and divide.  Thanks for your help!